# Missing App Store icon codename one build

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have created an app using codename one. It uploads to the google store for testing fine but when I try to upload it for TestFlight using the App Loader I get an error:

"Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/ for more information."

I have already uploaded a couple of versions for testing and they have uploaded fine.

I tried changing the icon to a 1024x1024 icon but it just defaulted back to 512x512.

How can I make sure this required icon is included with the build?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this should be fixed in the build servers now and should work for 9.2 builds too!

Comment: @ShaiAlmog brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to James H in a comment below.

This issue is due to Apple changing the required Xcode version to version 9. Codename one made a change to build apps using that version of Xcode.

You can set the build hint ios.xcode_version=7.3 to fix this.

There is a blog on codename one [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/xcode-9-on-by-default.html) that explains this issue more.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppIcon` you'll see a template for "App Store" icon of 1024x1024.

Drag your appropriately sized icon here.

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you do not see this template in the `AppIcon`, navigate to the `AppIcon.appiconset` directory in your project. (By right clicking on the `AppIcon` and selecting "Show in Finder")

Then edit the `Contents.json` file and add this item somewhere in there.

```
{
  "size" : "1024x1024",
  "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
  "scale" : "1x"
}
```

Now, the "App Store" template will appear in your `AppIcon`.

Comment: I have added that on iTunes connect but there is no option for it in codename one.

Comment: I had the same issue. I filed a bug on Github about this, and in the meantime I used the build hint to build with Xcode 7.3. Check the Codenameone blog, maybe a week or so ago.

Comment: @JamesH solution solved it for me. Thanks for your help though