# Apple refuse my codename one build for Apple Store

Tags: codenameone

Since yesterday I can't built my app for AppStore, I received this :

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
>   make you aware of them:
>
> Missing App Store Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store
>   Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or
>   via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta
>   App Review

It worked 2 days ago and I do only minor modifications.

Did Apple changes something ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well it literally tells you how to fix the problems. Have you tried doing those things?

Comment: Oh, I mistake codename1.arg.ios.NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and codename1.ios.NSMicrophoneUsageDescription. My bad :/

Comment: I have the same plist problem, and my app doesn't access photos nor microphone. My solution for now is to add the missing hints, and try to figure out what's going on later.

Comment: @YngveMoe I also ran into this, I assume it's the result of some bug in the cn1 build process.

Answer (score 0):

The AppStore icon part is to do with an error in Codename One changing the default Xcode version.

You can view my solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48965026/7255794). It was a question I asked and answered yesterday.